# CentOS x86 but PHP looking for mysql in /lib64/

Tags: php, mysql, centos6

It's straight, I don't know why PHP keep looking for mysql.so in /lib64 because my VPS is running CentOS 6.8 x86.

I have double check and don't see any reference to to /lib64 at all

1. **php.ini**: extension_dir = "./"
2. **my.ini**: extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/php_mysql.so

Here is httpd error log, any suggestion ?

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```